# Declaring private constants outside of a class in Swift

Tags: swift, constants, code-standards

When creating private constants in Swift it is possible to declare them within a class,

```
final class SomeClass: NSObject { 

    private let someFloat:CGFloat = 12
}
```

as well as outside of a class.

```
private let someFloat:CGFloat = 12

final class SomeClass: NSObject {  }
```

When outside of the class the scope is the file the constant is created in. Are there any other differences to using one method over the other, and does anyone have opinions on best practices?

Comment: In the first one, you are declaring a private constant per instance, though I think the compiler may optimize it to 1 constant for the whole class. The second method is more like how it's done in ObjC. Both are equivalent to me.

Comment: In addition to @CodeDifferent, your 2nd option would be available through all the classes created within that file.

Comment: Also consider overriding of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're accessed differently.

In the first case, `someFloat` is in the scope of `SomeClass`. It's accessed with `SomeClass.someFloat`.

In the second case, `someFloat` is in the module scope. It's accessed with just `someFloat`.

The first method is preferable. It's generally harder to find identifiers in the module name space, because they can be easily drowned out by all the identifiers in the standard library or foundation/cocoa framework.

Comment: Correct except the last paragraph. There is no global namespace. There is only module namespace. Also a private variable wont pollute anything.

Comment: @Sulthan You're right, I amended that mistake. I also clarified why the namespace pollution matters.